# Getting the mantissa (of a float) of either an unsigned int or a float (C)

Tags: c, ieee-754, mantissa

So, i am trying to program a function which prints a given float number (n) in its (mantissa * 2^exponent) format. I was abled to get the sign and the exponent, but not the mantissa (whichever the number is, mantissa is always equal to 0.000000). What I have is:

```
unsigned int num = *(unsigned*)&n;
unsigned int m = num & 0x007fffff;
mantissa = *(float*)&m;
```

Any ideas of what the problem might be?

Comment: [`frexp` etc.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/frexp) may come in handy here.

Comment: What you have breaks strict aliasing and is therefore undefined behavior.  If you want to do type-punning, you need to use unions.

Comment: Why do you want the mantissa as a `float`, when it fits a 32-bit `int`? Don't forget to include the implicit (not stored) most significant `1` bit of the mantissa / significand.

Comment: @WeatherVane i need the mantissa as a float so i can represent the number in the format m * 2^e (i think)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth can't use frexp

Comment: Are you are going round in circles? Isn't there a `printf` format specifier for that?

Comment: Undefined behaviour in two, implementation defined behaviour in one line. Three line, three problems … before starting disassemling floats, you should learn the basics.

Comment: You are not much on the *strict aliasing rule* are you? [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) Type punning pointers is a bad thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stripping off the bits of the exponent, leaving 0. An exponent of 0 is special, it means the number is denormalized and is quite small, at the very bottom of the range of representable numbers. I think you'd find if you looked closely that your result isn't quite exactly zero, just so small that you have trouble telling the difference.

To get a reasonable number for the mantissa, you need to put an appropriate exponent back in. If you want a mantissa in the range of 1.0 to 2.0, you need an exponent of 0, but adding the bias means you *really* need an exponent of 127.

```
unsigned int m = (num & 0x007fffff) | (127 << 23);
mantissa = *(float*)&m;
```

If you'd rather have a fully integer mantissa you need an exponent of 23, biased it becomes 150.

```
unsigned int m = (num & 0x007fffff) | ((23+127) << 23);
mantissa = *(float*)&m;
```

Answer (score 1):

The C library includes a function that does this exact task, [`frexp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/frexp):

```
int expon;
float mant = frexpf(n, &expon);
printf("%g = %g * 2^%d\n", n, mant, expon);
```

Another way to do it is with `log2f` and `exp2f`:

```
if (n == 0) {
  mant  = 0;
  expon = 0;
} else {
  expon = floorf(log2f(fabsf(n)));
  mant = n * exp2f(-expon);
}
```

These two techniques are likely to give different results for the same input.  For instance, on my computer the `frexpf` technique describes 4 as 0.5 × 2<sup>3</sup> but the `log2f` technique describes 4 as 1 × 2<sup>2</sup>.  Both are correct, mathematically speaking.  Also, `frexp` will give you the exact bits of the mantissa, whereas `log2f` and `exp2f` will probably round off the last bit or two.

---

You should know that `*(unsigned *)&n` and `*(float *)&m` violate the rule against "type punning" and have undefined behavior.  If you want to get the integer with the same bit representation as a float, or vice versa, use a union:

```
union { uint32_t i; float f; } u;
u.f = n;
num = u.i;
```

(Note: This use of unions is well-defined in C since roughly 2003, but, due to the C++ committee's long-standing habit of not paying sufficient attention to changes going into C, it is not officially well-defined in C++.)

You should also know IEEE floating-point numbers use "biased" exponents.  When you initialize a `float` variable's mantissa field but leave its exponent field at zero, that gives you the representation of a number with a *large negative* exponent: in other words, a number so small that `printf("%f", n)` will print it as zero.  Whenever `printf("%f", variable)` prints zero, change `%f` to `%g` or `%a` and rerun the program before assuming that `variable` actually is zero.

Comment: @Khosrow Why not?

Comment: because it's for college

Comment: Can you point at the 2003 standard/update? IIRC it was introduced formally in 1999 (C99) and common practice before.

Comment: @Olaf The original edition of C99 didn't explicitly require this, the wording was changed in an erratum.  Unfortunately I don't remember the DR number.

Comment: @Khosrow In that case, [this may help](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/s_frexpf.c;h=b7403bf0d8f48f895c59180be347f6a1aabfb8c4;hb=a700e7cb3799316e1b23879b4cf0891f5703acb1).

Comment: @zwol: Ah, that might explain it. I know the standard exactly only since 200x. Maybe the errata was editied into the version already.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to zwol's remarks: if you want to do it yourself you have to acquire some knowledge about the innards of an IEEE-754 float. Once you have done so you can write something like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>               // for testing only

typedef union {
  float value;
  unsigned int bits; // assuming 32 bit large ints (better: uint32_t)
} ieee_754_float;



// clang -g3 -O3 -W -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Weverything -std=c11 -o testthewest testthewest.c -lm
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  unsigned int m, num;
  int exp; // the exponent can be negative
  float n, mantissa;
  ieee_754_float uf;

  // neither checks nor balances included!

  if (argc == 2) {
    n = atof(argv[1]);
  } else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  uf.value = n;
  num = uf.bits;
  m = num & 0x807fffff;         // extract mantissa (i.e.: get rid of sign bit and exponent)
  num = num & 0x7fffffff;       // full number without sign bit
  exp = (num >> 23) - 126;      // extract exponent and subtract bias
  m |= 0x3f000000;              // normalize mantissa (add bias)
  uf.bits = m;
  mantissa = uf.value;
  printf("n = %g, mantissa = %g, exp = %d, check %g\n", n, mantissa, exp, mantissa * powf(2, exp));

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Note: the code above is one of the quick&dirty(tm) species and is not meant for production. It also lacks handling for subnormal (denormal) numbers, a thing you *must* include. Hint: multiply the mantissa with a large power of two (e.g.: 2^25 or in that ballpark) and adjust the exponent accordingly (if you took the value of my example subtract 25).

Comment: You might also want to add `#ifdef __STDC_IEC_559__` to check if your implementation is using an IEEE-754 float.